# T-SQL Fulltext search by first word

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, full-text-search

How can I perform "starts with" logic with full text search?

For example there is a `Contains` logic :

```
WHERE contains(Note,' "*word*" ')
```

I guess I need search by first word in the string, but how can I do it?

Comment: I don't think full text lets you you search by word position.   Why not just search the actual text?   Not clear if you want the first word in the whole string or just the start of each term.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WHERE CONTAINS (Note, ' "word*" ' );
```

Assuming "word" is the word that you are actually searching for.

Comment: It is not clear if they want the start of each term or the total input string.   I think this is correct for each term.